# U-sql - Error on defining input file pattern

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

In a U-SQL script invoked by an Azure data factory Pipeline, I have this statement to define an input file for my procedure: 
`DECLARE @inputpattern_csv string = "/FOLDER/" + @year.ToString() + @month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "{daynum:}_ex1.csv";`

The procedure has always worked, but now when I run it, it returns this error:
`E_CSC_USER_INVALIDFILESETPATTERN: Invalid file set pattern 'daynum:' in 'adl://**************.azuredatalakestore.net/FOLDER/201904{daynum:}_ex1.csv'`

And the error output on Azure Data Factory is the following:

```
{
"errorCode": "2703",
"message": "Error Id: E_CSC_USER_INVALIDFILESETPATTERN, Error Message: Invalid file set pattern 'daynum:' in 'adl://**************.azuredatalakestore.net/FOLDER/201904{daynum:}_ex1.csv'.. ",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "U-sql Activity"
}
```

Is a consequence of the update to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2? 
How I can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by:
"Is a consequence of the update to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2?"
Are you referring to moving from Gen1 to Gen2, or are you referring to a product update?

Comment: You don't need a colon after `daynum` if you don't specify format.

Answer (score -1):

It seem you are define the list file from the specify date range, right ?
If it correct, may be the code below will help you.

You can refer to MS's document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/concepts/files/input-files#inputfilesetpath)

```
DECLARE @File_Set_Pattern = "/sample/{Virtual_Col_Name:yyyy}/{Virtual_Col_Name:MM}/{Virtual_Col_Name:dd}.csv; 

DECLARE @From_Date = new DateTime(2019,01,01); 
DECLARE @To_Date = new DateTime(2019,01,28); 

@N = EXTRACT 
        Column_Names string, //define list columns and datatype here
        Virtual_Col_Name DateTime from @File_Set_Pattern //this is virtual column name
USING Extractors.Csv(); //replace by extractor you are using

OUTPUT( SELECT * FROM @N WHERE Virtual_Col_Name BETWEEN @From_Date AND @To_Date ) TO "/sample/outputfile.csv USING Outputters.Csv;
```

Comment: I don't have a range of dates to specify unfortunately! I would like to read all the files contained in a folder and the parameter of the date I must be able to put it every time I run the procedure